# Add photos to an existing Google Photos story

Tags: google-photos

Is there any way that I can add the new photos to a Google Photos auto-generated story?

The Google Photos assistant created a story for me for a vacation I took. I saved it, and then later uploaded more pictures from the vacation.

When I go to add photos, it is a subset of pictures that it must have originally deemed part of the story and you can turn them on and off individually, but I don't see anywhere to add a photo from my library.

Also, any way to change the “location” or landmarks that it guesses to correct ones?

Answer (score 1):

To add photos or videos:

**Android or iOS app**

1. Open the Google Photos app [image].
2. Open the story you want to update.
3. Touch the white background > add icon [image].
4. Choose moments to include.
5. At the top right, touch the checkmark [image].

**Computer**

1. Go to [your collections](https://photos.google.com/collections) and open the story you want to add to.
2. At the top right, click the add icon [image].
3. Choose moments to include.
4. At the bottom left, click **Done**.

---

To change a location:

1. To the right of the location name, touch or click the drop-down arrow.
2. Select the correct location. If you don't see it, you can remove the location.

[Source](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128852?hl=en).